# Performance Monitor most useful counters

Tags: windows, performance-monitor, perfmon

**Windows PerfMon** has many counters. A selection is suggested on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782186(WS.10).aspx but that's still a lot.

Which *counters* would you suggest as being the most useful to quickly see if a **remote machine has some problems**? Also to which scale would you set them?

Please not that I'm interested in **machine-wide** issues, not just issues related to ASP, Windows Service or any other specific kind. Only general info for a Windows server.

I only wish to know if the machine is working fine or if something fishy is going on. Kind of a green, orange, red light. If the counter can help identify the origin, then better but not a must. PerfMon *settings tips* are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Machine wide issues?

Forget setting counters.  Just download one of the many templates in that case.  Or use the default "System Performance" or "System Diagnostic" data counter sets.

If all you need is a green, orange, red light, then that is easy. Just follow the link you posted.  If you want a short short version, then....

Fire up Perfmon and click the plus to add counters.  Connect to target computer in the next window.
Then load up the following counters:

1. % CPU Time
2. Page Faults/sec
3. % of Disk time

Set the sample at 10 seconds(means it will take one sample every 10 seconds).